# Haskell FFI stack size with a C++ shared library

Tags: linux, haskell, ghc, ffi

I am trying to send a very large amount of data, on the order of several Gigabytes to Haskell via a shared library. Everything seems to work fine up to a point, but I eventually get the error:

Stack space overflow: current size 8388608 bytes.
Use `+RTS -Ksize' to increase it.

So basically, my question is: How do I increase the Haskell stack size?

I have tried:

1) Passing the appropriate -rtsopts flags to the linker when building the shared library -- No luck, but this is expected because I am using the Haskell as a shared library.

2) Calling hs_init with the RTS flags as described in this link:
[Haskell User Guide FFI/GHC](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.8.2/html/users_guide/ffi-ghc.html)...which did not work either.

```
int argc = 2;
char *argv[] = { "+RTS", "-K100M", NULL };
char **pargv = argv;

// Initialize Haskell runtime
hs_init(&argc, &pargv);
```

Basically I think that these arguments are also ignored because I am not using a Haskell main, which is also described in the user guide link I provided.

NOTE: I have also tried this approach adding a "-RTS" to the list before NULL and increasing argc but it made no difference.

3) I suspect that the true solution to this problem would be by following section 8.2.1.1 in the given link and making the special call to hs_init_ghc as so:

```
#include "HsFFI.h"
#include "Rts.h"

RtsConfig conf = defaultRtsConfig;
conf.rts_opts_enabled = RtsOptsAll;
hs_init_ghc(&argc, &argv, conf);
```

However when I try to do this as described in the guide, my C code that calls:

```
hs_init_ghc
```

will NOT compile due to a whole bunch of errors which I have pasted into the bottom of this question. It seems that including `RTS.h` will not compile, but I am following the example exactly, and compiling with:

```
ghc -c foo.cpp
```

I am wondering if anyone has any advice on how to get around this compilation error or to set the stack-size to a bigger value when using the Haskell as a shared library from C++?

I have also tried setting the corresponding environment variable, which also did not work. I even got a message saying it will be ignored.

I am using GHC version 7.4.1

Thanks very much for your help.

--JL

Compilation errors are:

>

> In file included from /usr/lib/ghc/include/Rts.h:222:0:
>      0,                    from foo.cpp:6:
>
> /usr/lib/ghc/include/rts/storage/Block.h:227:26:
>        error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘new’
>        dbl_link_replace(bdescr *new, bdescr *old, bdescr **list)
>                                 ^
>   /usr/lib/ghc/include/rts/storage/Block.h: In function ‘void dbl_link_replace(bdescr*)’:
>
> /usr/lib/ghc/include/rts/storage/Block.h:229:8:
>        error: expected type-specifier before ‘->’ token
>            new->link = old->link;
>               ^
>
> /usr/lib/ghc/include/rts/storage/Block.h:229:8:
>        error: expected ‘;’ before ‘->’ token
>
> /usr/lib/ghc/include/rts/storage/Block.h:230:8:
>        error: expected type-specifier before ‘->’ token
>            new->u.back = old->u.back;
>               ^
>
> /usr/lib/ghc/include/rts/storage/Block.h:230:8:
>        error: expected ‘;’ before ‘->’ token
>
> /usr/lib/ghc/include/rts/storage/Block.h:231:9:
>        error: ‘old’ was not declared in this scope
>            if (old->link) {
>                ^
>
> /usr/lib/ghc/include/rts/storage/Block.h:232:32:
>        error: expected type-specifier before ‘;’ token
>                old->link->u.back = new;
>                                       ^
>
> /usr/lib/ghc/include/rts/storage/Block.h:234:9:
>        error: ‘old’ was not declared in this scope
>            if (old->u.back) {
>                ^
>
> /usr/lib/ghc/include/rts/storage/Block.h:235:32:
>        error: expected type-specifier before ‘;’ token
>                old->u.back->link = new;
>                                       ^
>
> /usr/lib/ghc/include/rts/storage/Block.h:237:10:
>        error: ‘list’ was not declared in this scope
>                *list = new;
>                 ^
>
> /usr/lib/ghc/include/rts/storage/Block.h:237:20:
>        error: expected type-specifier before ‘;’ token
>                *list = new;
>                          ^
>
> In file included from /usr/lib/ghc/include/Rts.h:218:0:
>       0,
>                        from foo.cpp:6:
>   /usr/lib/ghc/include/rts/storage/ClosureMacros.h: In function ‘rtsBool
>
> More compile errors removed...but available upon request.

Comment: Is your code written in C++?  The compile error looks like the GHC headers are only designed to work in C.

Comment: Uh yeah, I feel kind of stupid now. Just changed the file extension to ".c" from ".cpp" and it worked fine. If you want to post your comment as an answer that would definitely be cool. Thank you VERY much by the way!

Comment: So, how do you do this if the main program is in C++?